# Qmail - Local Queue stacking up

Tags: azure, ssh, dns, plesk, qmail

I have a big problem!
My customer contacted me, and told me that he isn't recieving emails from his websites contactform. I checked the mail-queue in Plesk, and I can see that they're stuck in "local"(!)

I tried to force send by running this in SSH `kill -ALRM` `ps ax | grep [q]mail-send | awk '{print $1}'`

It's not working - returns a empty line in my SSH.
I have tried similar solutions - but no luck.
Is there anything I can do, to get some more information about this issue?
I'm not an expert in Plesk at all - and all the help I can get is GREATLY appreciated.

**Maillog:**

```
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail-local-handlers[28962]: from=lyg@lyg.dk
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail-local-handlers[28962]: to=opening.dk-ak@opening.dk
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail-local-handlers[28962]: mailbox: /var/qmail/mailnam                                                 es/opening.dk
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.408838 delivery 55: deferral: /bin/sh:                                                 _/deliverquota:_No_such_file_or_directory/
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.408855 status: local 5/10 remote 0/20
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.411033 delivery 57: deferral: /bin/sh:                                                 _/deliverquota:_No_such_file_or_directory/
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.411060 status: local 4/10 remote 0/20
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.412893 delivery 54: deferral: /bin/sh:                                                 _/deliverquota:_No_such_file_or_directory/
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.412910 status: local 3/10 remote 0/20
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.414351 delivery 53: deferral: /bin/sh:                                                 _/deliverquota:_No_such_file_or_directory/
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.414369 status: local 2/10 remote 0/20
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.414377 delivery 58: deferral: /bin/sh:                                                 _/deliverquota:_No_such_file_or_directory/
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.414384 status: local 1/10 remote 0/20
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.414554 delivery 56: deferral: /bin/sh:                                                 _/deliverquota:_No_such_file_or_directory/
Mar 29 08:14:12 opening qmail: 1490775252.414570 status: local 0/10 remote 0/20
Mar 29 08:14:41 opening qmail-queue-handlers[29038]: Unable to change group ID:                                                  Operation not permitted
Mar 29 08:14:41 opening qmail: 1490775281.517412 warning: trouble injecting boun                                                 ce message, will try later
Mar 29 08:14:41 opening qmail-queue-handlers[29039]: Unable to change group ID:                                                  Operation not permitted
Mar 29 08:14:41 opening qmail: 1490775281.518755 warning: trouble injecting boun                                                 ce message, will try later
```

And if I run `ps -ef|grep mail` I get the following output:

```
[opening@opening log]$ ps -ef|grep mail
qmails   28182     1  0 08:10 ?        00:00:00 qmail-send
qmaill   28184 28182  0 08:10 ?        00:00:00 splogger qmail
root     28185 28182  0 08:10 ?        00:00:00 qmail-lspawn | /deliverquota ./Maildir
qmailr   28186 28182  0 08:10 ?        00:00:00 qmail-rspawn
qmailq   28187 28182  0 08:10 ?        00:00:00 qmail-clean
opening  29554 28582  0 08:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mail
root     64808     1  0 Mar23 ?        00:01:10 /usr/bin/spamd --nouser-config --username=popuser --daemonize --helper-home-dir=/var/qmail --virtual-config-dir=/var/qmail/mailnames/%d/%l/.spamassassin --create-prefs --max-children=5 -r /var/run/spamd.pid
```

When I run `plesk repair mail -y -v` I get the following output:

```
[opening@opening log]$ sudo plesk repair mail -y -v Repairing the mail server configuration Reconfiguring all domains and mailboxes ......................... [OK] Error messages: 0; Warnings: 0; Errors resolved: 0
```

Btw. Plesk is installed on an Azure server - if that is to any help at all.

Please let me know if I can provide any other info - and how.

Best regards

Aris Kuckovic

Comment: You had better restart your service, I don't suggest you kill the process directly.  Check your service log firstly. You could refer https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213403509-Plesk-for-Linux-services-logs-and-configuration-files-#plesk

Comment: Hi Walter,

I just restarted the service - no luck.
This is what I saw in my Maillog:

https://paste.ofcode.org/ij98Mfr2FqqLQqZNzJdy6Y

Comment: `ps -ef|grep mail` check the mail process

Comment: I get this output: https://paste.ofcode.org/Q7zyRpShEdNYTW4fdVYXSb

Comment: Add logs to your question, more people could help you.

Comment: It's done - thanks a lot Walter :)

Answer (score 0):

If you experience issues/errors/problems with QMAIL on servers where **Plesk** ( > 12.5 ) is installed, consider to use the "**Plesk repair utility**" with the example command :

```
plesk repair mail -y -v
```

More possible options for the "**Plesk repair utility**" can be found at:

**=>** [**Plesk Repair Utility** *( official Plesk online documentation - Administrator's Guide )*](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/plesk-repair-utility.74649/)

---

Another option to solve possible issues/errors/problems is to switch from QMAIL to POSTFIX and backwards to QMAIL again:

```
plesk installer --select-product-id plesk --select-release-current --install-component postfix

plesk installer --select-product-id plesk --select-release-current --install-component qmail
```

Comment: Hi UFHH01, thanks a lot for the plesk repair command - unfortunately, it didn't return any errors. `[opening@opening log]$ sudo plesk repair mail -y -v

Repairing the mail server configuration
    Reconfiguring all domains and mailboxes ......................... [OK]

Error messages: 0; Warnings: 0; Errors resolved: 0
`

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Mar 29 08:14:41 opening qmail-queue-handlers[29038]: Unable to change group ID:Operation not permitted
```

suggests that it maybe because of a permissions issue. You should open a ticket with Plesk support or check on their forums.

You can also switch to postfix as it is more widely used

Comment: Hi Nadir, thanks for your reply. In the meanwhile we found another solution for this customer - we added a third-party SMTP. We have contacted Plesk aswell, and are awaiting further assistance. Thanks a lot!